# Handling QR code out of sight

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

Right now I handle the recognition of a QR-code with

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

from `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`. But is it possible to handle that a QR-Code is no longer visible (outside of the camera view, or rather, it cant be recognized anymore)?

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer visible"?

Comment: I mean it is outside of the camera view, or rather, it cant be recognized anymore

Comment: While the code is still visible you will get repeated callbacks. You can start a timer when you get a callback and restart it each time. When the timer fires you know that the code is no longer visible